# Deserializing enum with lowercase - Java/Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I've a Project class with these attributes

```
private String id;
private String name;
private ProjectStatus status;
```

Projectstatus is an enum like this:

```
public enum ProjectStatus {
    I,
    A,
    C,
    OPEN,
    CLOSED
}
```

I'm calling a remote rest service which responds with json to pull information about the project.

The issue I'm having is that the status in the remote service payload is 'Open' which causes an issue while trying to create the Project object as the status in my ProjectStatus enum is OPEN, all uppercase.

I could create the ProjectStatus like this to match the response from the service:

```
public enum ProjectStatus {
    I,
    A,
    C,
    Open,
    Closed
}
```

However, I'd be violating the standard to name enums.

I've also tried to do the following without success

```
public enum ProjectStatus {
    I,
    A,
    C,
    OPEN("Open"),
    CLOSED("Closed")
}
```

What's the right way to go here?

Comment: Why not simply call `toUpperCase` on the string before converting it into an enum?

Comment: Add property to enum (like String responseStatus) and replace ProjectStatus into  String in your Project class. And then match String with your Enum.

Comment: Can you make [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, which library are you using to deserialize, i suppose jackson?

Answer (score 0):

Easies solution would be defining Value to what will be serialized via `@JsonValue` Annotation. Something along this lines

```java
public enum MySuperEnum {
    VALUE_1("value1", "Value 1 Desc"),
    VALUE_2("valu2", "Value 2 Desc"),
    VALUE_3("value3", "Value 3 Desc")
    ;

    private final String code;
    private final String desc;

    MySuperEnum(String code, String desc){
        this.code = code;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getDesc(){
        return desc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this

```
public enum ProjectStatus {
    I("I"),
    A("A"),
    C("C"),
    OPEN("Open"),
    CLOSED("Closed");

    private String value;

    ProjectStatus(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static ProjectStatus fromString(String value) {
        return ProjectStatus.valueOf(value.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```